# RecyclerView is displaying no data on screen if used in a second activity but showing list if used in launcher activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

On button click from first activity(RollDiceActivity.java) I’m going to the 2nd activity where my recyclerview is fetching JSON object(Using Volley).My code is simple:

```
viewQuotesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // created explicit intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(RollDiceActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("addedRandomNo", addedRandomNo);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Second Activity- MainActivity.java, where the recyclerView is but the recyclerview is not showing any data on screen (but Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + "Size: "+response.length()); gives me all the JSON object that is being fetched)

```
package com.subhasishlive.recyclerviewexplanation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Adapter.MyAdapter;
import Model.ListItem;
import Util.Constants;
import Util.Prefs;

/**
 * Created by SubhasishNath on 6/11/2018.
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "getting length" ;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private List<ListItem> listItems;// listitems are movies...
    private RequestQueue queue;// to use volleys

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // we are adding our queue and passing our current context....
            queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        // TODO: A FAB button would be added to call an alert dialog for search...


        // now we will set up our recyclerview and setup the adapter.
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        // creating an instance of Prefs class, calling parameterized constructor
        // passing our mainActivity as parameter...
        //Prefs prefs = new Prefs(MainActivity.this);
        // calling getSearch() method
        //String search = prefs.getSearch();

        // ArrayLists are capable of holding any type of lists
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        // listItems is set to the returning value of getMovies(), which is a List<ListItem>
        // so listItems holds all the movies returned by the search parameter.
        listItems = getMovies();

        adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,listItems);// creating a new adapter for our listItems.
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);//setting our adapter for our recyclerView.
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify any registered observers that the data set has changed.
    }

    // creating a method to get movies...
    public List<ListItem> getMovies(){
        listItems.clear(); // first we're clearing the movie list....


        JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.base_url + "wp/v2/AllQuotes",new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // TODO:response holds the whole JSON object from the URL
                try{
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + "Size: "+response.length());
                    // instantiated a new JSON array.
                    // Pass the name of the JSON array as parameter.
                    // Search is name of the JSON array from the JSON file
                    //JSONArray moviesArray = response.getJSONArray("Search");
                    // Now I'm iterating through the array by a for loop
                    // every index-element in that array contains a JSON object.
                    for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                        // instanciating JSONObject variable to pick a Index item(which is a JSON object) from the JSONArray.
                        //JSONObject movieObj =  moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListItem movie = new ListItem();// creating ListItem object.
                        Log.d(TAG,"Object at " + i+ response.get(i));
                        // getting the JSONObject at i-th position of the JSONArray
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        // fetching id of each JSONObject from JSONArray.
                        movie.setId(obj.getInt("id"));

                        // title itself is an object so first I'm retrieving that
                        JSONObject titleObj=obj.getJSONObject("title");
                        // using title object I'm retrieving the string in it.
                        movie.setTitle(titleObj.getString("rendered"));

                        // content itself is an object so first I'm retriving that.
                        JSONObject contentObj = obj.getJSONObject("content");
                        // setting up the content
                        movie.setContent(contentObj.getString("rendered"));

                        // getting image object and setting up image.
                        JSONObject imgObj = obj.getJSONObject("better_featured_image");
                        movie.setPostImg(imgObj.getString("source_url"));


                        // getting excerpt object and setting up excerpt.
                        JSONObject excerptObj = obj.getJSONObject("excerpt");
                        movie.setPostExcerpt(excerptObj.getString("rendered"));


                        // adding the newly created movie to listItems list...
                        listItems.add(movie);
                    }

                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); // throwing an exception
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO: Handle error

            }
        });

        queue.add(getRequest);
        return listItems;

    }
}
```

But if I'm changing the second activity(MainActivity.java) to be my launching activity in AndroidManifest.xml, then it is displaying all the items of recyclerView on the screen as well as the log is showing.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Any help will be appreciated. I'm confused as the problem seems stupid. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify your `adapter` after adding data in your `listItems` list

Try this

Use **`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`**
 after adding data in your `listItems` inside `onResponse()` method in your `getMovies()` Method

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public List<ListItem> getMovies(){
        listItems.clear(); // first we're clearing the movie list....


        JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.base_url + "wp/v2/AllQuotes",new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // TODO:response holds the whole JSON object from the URL
                try{
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + "Size: "+response.length());
                    // instantiated a new JSON array.
                    // Pass the name of the JSON array as parameter.
                    // Search is name of the JSON array from the JSON file
                    //JSONArray moviesArray = response.getJSONArray("Search");
                    // Now I'm iterating through the array by a for loop
                    // every index-element in that array contains a JSON object.
                    for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                        // instanciating JSONObject variable to pick a Index item(which is a JSON object) from the JSONArray.
                        //JSONObject movieObj =  moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListItem movie = new ListItem();// creating ListItem object.
                        Log.d(TAG,"Object at " + i+ response.get(i));
                        // getting the JSONObject at i-th position of the JSONArray
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        // fetching id of each JSONObject from JSONArray.
                        movie.setId(obj.getInt("id"));

                        // title itself is an object so first I'm retrieving that
                        JSONObject titleObj=obj.getJSONObject("title");
                        // using title object I'm retrieving the string in it.
                        movie.setTitle(titleObj.getString("rendered"));

                        // content itself is an object so first I'm retriving that.
                        JSONObject contentObj = obj.getJSONObject("content");
                        // setting up the content
                        movie.setContent(contentObj.getString("rendered"));

                        // getting image object and setting up image.
                        JSONObject imgObj = obj.getJSONObject("better_featured_image");
                        movie.setPostImg(imgObj.getString("source_url"));


                        // getting excerpt object and setting up excerpt.
                        JSONObject excerptObj = obj.getJSONObject("excerpt");
                        movie.setPostExcerpt(excerptObj.getString("rendered"));


                        // adding the newly created movie to listItems list...
                        listItems.add(movie);
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); // throwing an exception
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO: Handle error

            }
        });

        queue.add(getRequest);
        return listItems;

    }
```

Comment: You just saved my life,it is my first app and I got stuck just before completing it. thanks bro :))